# restart via code on windows 10 uwp

Tags: windows-10, uwp, system.diagnostics

We've created a Windows 10 application that runs on tablets in Windows 10 kiosk mode. It works just fine, however, the wifi connection gets lost sometimes since the locations are very remote. We tried fixing the issue from the networking side, but when the devices lose and regain internet access the application will still hang as if it doesn't have internet access displaying a blank page. Where these devices are used, they are bolted into the wall to prevent theft. Which means if we want to reboot its very time consuming as we have to unscrew the cases off the wall and then open the cases to gain access to the power button, and the only way to get the application to run successfully again is to do a reboot on the device.

It was suggested that we have a way to perform a reboot from the application, however, every code example I've tried doesn't work in Windows 10 UWP. Here is the most common one I've found:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("restart", "/r");
```

I have access to the namespace

```
System.Diagnostics
```

but the Process class does not exist. Anyone have suggestions on rebooting via code on Win 10 UWP? Or a better solution to our issue? Thanks in advance.

It's also worth mentioning I tried execute a Powershell command too and the dll I need to reference for the Powershell class is not compatible with UWP.

Comment: Not possible. I'd suggest to hunt the bug which makes the restarts necessary firsthand or use a non-UWP app.

Comment: Look for alternative solutions other than rebooting that perhaps the Win 10 sandbox will allow, e.g. Perhaps power-cycling Flight Mode to fix, or somehow triggering network connection to clear, then maybe you can code these options.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies, I'll look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you require is not possible with the APIs available to UWP apps. This was a security decision. An app distributed through the store shouldn't be able to do things like restart machines.

Based on your scenario though you shouldn't need to go through the store. This means that you could PInvoke native code to do whatever you want.  This would still need to be initiated on the actual device.

Comment: You're correct, I'm sideloading the application and not publishing it to the store. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does sideloading enable calling APIs that would otherwise be restricted? My understanding was that sideloading merely emulates a Windows Store deployment and thus I assumed would be subject to the same security limitations. Is this not the case?

Comment: @devios If sideloading it doesn't go through the checks the store does to make sure you're not using something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that!
You should add **IoT System Administration** in App capability declarations:

```
<Capabilities><iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/></Capabilities>
```

and also You need to have **"Windows IoT Extension for UWP"** added to your project

using this for **Shutdown**

```
Windows.System.ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));        //Delay is not relevant to shutdown
```

or for **Restart**

```
Windows.System.ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));     //Delay before restart after shutdown
```

You can get more information in this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)

Comment: IoT extension are only meant for windows IoT devices

Comment: Yes, this will not work for PCs. Microsoft is smarter than that.