# queryPerformanceFrequency in C# UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

I would like to call queryPerformanceFrequency function in Windows 10 C# UWP app.

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

does not seem to work

How should I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Try read this post [How to get diagnostic statistics from a UWP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708279/how-to-get-diagnostic-statistics-from-a-uwp-app)