# What is the length of an lp variable?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm a C# developer so to solve this I try MSDN and StackOverflow. Unfortunately, they seem to conflict here. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381404(v=vs.85).aspx)  states that it will depend on the architecture - 64 bits for a 64 bit process and 32 bits for 32 bit one. SO, on the other hand has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775852/939213) describing [SYSTEM_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx)   that seems to indicate that it's always 32 bits because `MinimumApplicationAddress` and `MaximumApplicationAddress` are defined as `UInt32`s even though the question is tagged with **win-universal-app** which is more often x64 than x86. (Yes, I know that doesn't mean that *every* process will be 64 bits.)

Comment: @Ðаn I'm trying to call GetSystemInfo from C#. So you're saying that the SO answer has it inexact - that will only work in 32 bit processes. Correct?

Comment: @Ðаn I'm trying to get system info in UWP

Comment: @Ðаn That is very limited. No cpu use, for example. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LP` is a Microsoft prefix notation (known as Hungarian notation) that indicates a pointer. Originally it was short for “long pointer”, which made sense in DOS programming. For 32-bit code it's 32 bits, and for 64-bit code it's 64 bits.

Comment: So you're saying that the SO answer I linked to has it inexact, it will only work on 32 bit processes. Correct?

Comment: @ispiro: I'm not sure, I glanced at that answer and didn't see anything relevant? But *if* it says what you say it says, then it's just wrong.

Comment: I looked more at it, it looks just wrong, 32-bit specific code. Hopefully in .NET there must be something called `IntPtr` or the like, an int that corresponds to pointer size.

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about a uint32, that is guaranteed to be 32 bits, if you are talking about an int pointer, that will vary from system to system, so yes it just depends on what the underlying code is and what it's doing that will determine this.